# htaccess restrições

Tags: php, htaccess

Gostaria de limpar a minha `url` para que o usuário não a veja,procurei na internet mas mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

Já ativei as livrarias no meu **wamp** mas não consegui fazer funcionar corretamente.

www.meusite.com.br/index.php?p=contato&assunto=trabalhe

preciso manter toda a estrutura mas gostaria que o **cliente apenas visualizasse**:

www.meusite.com.br/contato/trabalhe

Como posso fazer?

Efetuei alguns testes e cheguei no seguinte fonte:

.htaccess

```
#reescrita
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/$ index.php?p=$1&assunto=$2 [NC,L]
```

html

```
<a href="pagina/teste/">action</a>
<a href="pagina2/teste2/">action2</a>
```

Mas quando clicar na segunda opção de link ele não limpa url, apenas incrementa apresentando erro, como corrigir?

www.pagina.com.br/pagina2/teste2/pagina/teste/

Comment: Isso se trata de url amigáveis, dê uma olhada em: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas/ e http://wbruno.com.br/php/desmistificando-urls-amigaveis-com-php-e-htaccessapache/

Comment: cuidado com as aceitações de edição supérfluas pessoal... em caso de dúvida, está ali o botão ´pular´ na fila de análises. aquela primeira edição quase nem mudou nada da pergunta.

Comment: @Chun eu aprovei, mais voltei atrás e editei. Vacilo meo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que seu `href` está assim (relativo ao `path` atual):

```
pagina/teste/
```

Deveria estar assim:

```
/pagina/teste/
```

Comment: vlw, funcionou.
agora preciso saber como ocultar dentro da url uma pasta.

Comment: @BrunoCoió quando vc fala de "ocultar dentro da url uma pasta", vc quer dizer - ocultar os ficheiros dentro dela para que o usuário não acesse o 'esqueleto', ou seja as sub-pastas deste arquivo?

Comment: por exemplo, esconder a pasta '/teste' do link, ou até mesmo um registro 'id=12'